# Merge two data frames based on values of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two data frames

```
data1 = {'ID': [385908, 385909, 757947, 757946],
         'A': ['LH', 'LH', 'LH', 'LH'],
         'F': [646, 646, 646, 646],
         'Orig': ['FRA', 'FRA', 'NQZ', 'NQZ'],
         'Dest': ['NQZ', 'NQZ', 'ALA', 'ALA'],
         'DayU': [1, 6, 1, 6],
         'DepU': [650, 650, 1130, 1130]}

data2 = {'A': ['LH', 'LH', 'LH', 'LH', 'LH', 'LH'],
         'F': [646, 646, 646, 646, 646, 646],
         'Orig2': ['FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA', 'NQZ', 'NQZ'],
         'Dest2': ['ALA', 'ALA', 'NQZ', 'NQZ', 'ALA', 'ALA'],
         'DayL': [1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 7],
         'DepL': [710, 710, 710, 710, 50, 50],
         'IDL1': [385908, 385909, 385908, 385909, 757947, 757946],
         'IDL2': [757947, 757946, -1, -1, -1, -1]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I would like to add columns to df1 from df2 based on the IDL1,IDL2,ID values.

Where I have ID=IDL1 or ID=IDL2 I would like to add Orig2 and Dest2 into df1.
This is the expected output:
In this example: First two rows ID=IDL1 & last two rows ID=IDL2.

```
    data3 = {'ID': [385908, 385909, 757947, 757946],
             'A': ['LH', 'LH', 'LH', 'LH'],
             'F': [646, 646, 646, 646],
             'Orig': ['FRA', 'FRA', 'NQZ', 'NQZ'],
             'Dest': ['NQZ', 'NQZ', 'ALA', 'ALA'],
             'DayU': [1, 6, 1, 6],
             'DepU': [650, 650, 1130, 1130],
             'Orig2':['FRA','FRA','FRA','FRA'],
             'Dest2':['ALA','ALA','ALA','ALA'],
             'DayL': [1, 6, 1, 6]}
    }
```

This is a simplified solution, I would like to have a general solution. Thank you

Edit: I want to merge df1 and df2 such that if a ID row in df1 matches either IDL1 or IDL2 in df2, and the combination of Orig and Dest from df1 is different from the combination of Orig2 and Dest2.
For ID equal to 757947 where Orig=FRA & Dest=NQZ, I have multiple matches, IDL2=757947 with (Orig2=FRA & Dest2=ALA) & IDL2=757947 with (Orig2=FRA & Dest=NQZ). In this case I match where I have Orig2+Dest2 not equal to Orig+Dest.

Comment: Having little confusion on the data. In the example if Id = 757947 it is available in both id1 and id2 but you have update the rows based on id2. if the id present in both id1 and id2 how you want the output?

Comment: @udaykumargajavalli good question, I want to take the case where ID=IDL1 or ID=IDL2 but we have Orig+Dest different than Orig2+Dest2. In this case I want ID=IDL2=757947 because Orig+Dest=NQZALA while Orig2+Dest2=FRAALA and I disregard the cases where Orig+Dest is equal to Orig2+Dest2. Does it make sense ?

Comment: This is not clear at all. Please provide clear logic. Your explanation does not handle the case where there are multiple values for ID1. Please provide row-by-row explanation of why each row in the sample has the value it does.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
tmp = df2.melt(['Orig2', 'Dest2', 'DayL'], value_vars=['IDL1', 'IDL2'], value_name='ID')
tmp2 = df1.merge(tmp.drop('variable', axis=1), how='left')
out= tmp2[tmp2['Orig'].ne(tmp2['Orig2']) | tmp2['Dest'].ne(tmp2['Dest2'])]
```

out

```
       ID   A    F Orig Dest  DayU  DepU Orig2 Dest2  DayL
0  385908  LH  646  FRA  NQZ     1   650   FRA   ALA     1
2  385909  LH  646  FRA  NQZ     6   650   FRA   ALA     6
5  757947  LH  646  NQZ  ALA     1  1130   FRA   ALA     1
7  757946  LH  646  NQZ  ALA     6  1130   FRA   ALA     6
```